# Caption of figure from PDF overlap page number and at the end of page

Tags: graphics, pdf

I have a drawing from Word 2010. As I would like to insert this drawing into latex, I save this Word file as pdf file. Then I insert the pdf file into latex using includegraphics. Although the size of drawing is small, this drawing jumps into the new page in latex and the caption in the end of page and overlap the page number (there is a huge blank between the figure and the caption). How can I make the drawing still keep the same page of the text and the caption just below the figure? The figure as following: [image]

This is my code :

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
       \captionsetup{justification=centering}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]{D:/01_Publication/Figures/Fig4_nhap}
         \caption{The figure4.}
     \label{fig:4}
     \end{figure}
```

Comment: A minimal example that people can compile will help get this question more attention.

Comment: Did you crop the pdf before including it in LaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comment. I already fixed my problems by using this code:

```
\includegraphics[clip, trim=0cm 20.75cm 0cm 2.5cm,width=\linewidth]{filename}.
```